# what are benefits of upgrading to snow leopard..?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have currently Leopard version 10.5.8 installed & I am thinking to upgrading to snow leopard but I want to be sure what enhancements will I get

googling has revealed that only under the hood enhancements have been made ....

I am pretty happy with my current OS

should I upgrade ....?

its only 29$ I believe for me right... but still .....what are your comments........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It's a bit faster, including startup and shut down
- It takes up less disk space
- Certain applications that take advantage of the new developer features will run faster (64-bit and Grand Central Dispatch)
- Most of the applications have been updated to newer versions, including Safari and QuickTime
- The Dock, Stacks, and Exposé were enhanced
- Other aesthetic changes

(For a full list see [Apple's page](http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/enhancements-refinements.html))

Basically, **yes, you should upgrade**. The $29 is worth it.

Comment: LOTS of under the hood changes along with about 10GB more disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded two machines (a MacBook Pro and a MacPro).  On both systems, the upgrade freed up over **10 GB** of disk space.  And, in general, it *seems* faster, although I haven't done any measurements :-).

Personally, that was good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would, it's nice to use the latest and greatest.

There are a few nice improvements to the dock, stacks and exposé which I would say are worth the $29 if you use the system as your primary computer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 64bit application, and have some scrolling advanced in dock.